# Is it legal to use a brands name in products title?

Tags: international, commerce, branding

Amazon keeps deactivating listings for this reason. The reason that i am using their name is;
I am producing product for (compatible) their products. Titles are like "Bag for XXBRAND XXMODEL".
I have to use their name to reach correct customers(search engines). Amazon told me to write a line that describes i am not associated with the brand(as i understand). My native language is not English so: How can i explain this in formal language? Or is it legal to use their name like this?

Answer (score 1):

Companies, like Apple, have what are called “trademarks” on their names for specific markets. This means, for instance, that Apple can sue any company that uses their name and likeness to sell any device that might compete with Apple.

As these companies are likely selling their own products that might compete with yours. Companies also don’t want people using their name to sell products that might be inferior. The use of the company name might cause consumers to associate your product with your product.

There is no way around trademarks, especially in the title of a product. While in the product listing you should be able to list “compatible with XXX” you cannot add that to the name of the product.